# How do I correctly use the CloudWatch boto3 API to retrieve data from metrics?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatch-metrics

I'm using Python3's boto3 to try to pull data from SQS's metrics using the get_metric_statistics function documented here:

https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/cloudwatch.html#CloudWatch.Client.get_metric_statistics

This is the code I made to try to pull it:

```
import boto3
import sys
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

client = boto3.client('cloudwatch')

response = client.get_metric_statistics(
    Namespace='SQS',
    MetricName='NumberOfEmptyReceives',
    Dimensions=[
        {
            'Name' : 'QueueName',
            'Value' : 'AlertNotifications'
        }
    ],  
    StartTime=datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(seconds=600),
    EndTime=datetime.utcnow(),
    Period=60,
    Statistics=[
        'Sum'
    ]
)

print(response)
sys.exit(0)
```

I get a response from the API, with a HTTP status code 200, so that worked, but I get no data points. I also double checked that I'm calling the correct profile using boto3.setup_default_session().

I also double checked that my data existed: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRGQo.png

Does anybody spot what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try removing some of your filters and try again - if you got a 200 back, it's likely that the call succeeded, but nothing existed within the filters you're sending.

Comment: I'm not sure which filters I would remove. Starttime and endtime are required.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Namespace needs to be prepended with AWS/
e.g 'AWS/SQS'

See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/aws-namespaces.html

Comment: holy crap that actually worked. I didn't think I'd get this one answered 3 months later. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Give the thing a Unit parameter too. I've had some cloudwatch metrics return back nothing if I didn't include a Unit in my request.